# python - saved in different format when inserting datetime.min and datetime.now() into mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, datetime

I'd like to insert `datetime.min` into my mongodb collection.

When I tried it, the result value is saved as `-62135596800000`. What I've expected was `0001-01-01 00:00:00.000Z` or `0001-01-01 00:00:00`.

If I inserted `datetime.now()`, it is saved as `2022-05-06 04:59:48.323Z`,

Both `type(datetime.now())` and `type(datetime.min)` return `datetime.datetime`, but why is this difference made?

The code i've tried is below,

```
data = dict()
data['now'] = {'ref_time': datetime.now()}
data['min'] = {'ref_time': datetime.min}

myClient.db['mydb'].insert_one(data)

# the result
#{
#    "_id" : ObjectId("62749f91e7304516a6dedf04"),
#    "now" : {
#        "ref_time" : ISODate("2022-05-06T13:09:53.815Z")
#    },
#    "min" : {
#        "ref_time" : Date(-62135596800000)
#    }
#}
```

Comment: `ISODate("0001-01-01T00:00:00Z")` and `Date(-62135596800000)` are same values.

Comment: @prasad_ ah, I see. then what should I do to save `ISODate("0000-01-01T00:00:00Z")`, instead of `Date(-621355968000000)` in mongodb?

Comment: When I saved the data using your code (PyMongo), it printed as: `'min': {'ref_time': datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0)}`.  So, it should not matter.

Comment: I saved with pymongo and see inner data using `Robo 3T` , it prints `Date(-62135596800000)`, but the `datetime.now` is printed  `ISODate("2022-05-06T13:09:53.815Z")`....

Comment: That's the tool you are using which is printing / showing as so - I think. Try using mongosh (or mongo shell or Compass) and see.

Comment: @prasad_ you were right. I use mongo compass to see data, it prints `0001-01-01 09:00:00.000` well. maybe I need to save data in ISODate instead Date format or modify print option in robo 3t unless I can change my team's db tool..

Comment: Compass has a Analyze Schema TAB to view the data types - it will show the data type of the stored values.